# GWT IndexedDB available or any update on this?

Tags: gwt

is there any update on GWT IndexedDB?
Here are two projects of GWT IndexedDB but i dont know if this is usefull because these two projects seem to be dead?!

http://code.google.com/p/indexeddb-gwt/
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-indexeddb/

IS it possible to use GWT IndexedDB by JSNI? Has anybody experience with it?

Would like to learn and to use IndexedDB but dont know because iam using only GWT and not JavaScript.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any pure javascript/browser functaonlity from `GWT` using `JSNI`.

If youu look at the above linked Indexdb gwt libraries they do just that. They define `JSO` Overlay wrappers for the corresponding javascript objects. (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/indexeddb-gwt/source/browse/trunk/src/com/os/idb/client/IDBTransaction.java) as an example).

Alternatively you could also look into the [Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html) library. I am not 100% sure but it might contain wrappers for IndexDB.

So you have 4 choices:

1. Manually call the indexdb javascript functons using `JSNI`.
2. Write your own wrapper using `JSO` and `JSNI`
3. Use on of the indexdb GWT wrappers
4. Use `Elemental` library.

Answer (score 0):

I used java Maps (TreeMap) package to emulate indexedDB searching functions and GWT built-in html5 storage wrapper to store data offline in browser.